# How to fix 'Error: Cannot find module '/lib/index' on Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm adding 1 new library to my project (express-fileupload), but, when run  node server this return that message, I tried with the commands:

- npm install
- npm loader
- npm install winston (this for a problem reported in a Github project)
- npm start

but this dont work.

```
$ node server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/lib/index'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\david\Documents\INTRANET\dusoft-server\server.js:15:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
```

Comment: How are you importing this library to your project? If you've only installed it and it doesn't work you should open an issue for that library's github (whether it's caused by express-fileupload or winston).

Comment: In the project, I'm import the library like this: https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example